# Product of three supersoluble subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I need a proof of the following statement:

1. Let a finite group $G=AB=AC=BC$ be the product of three supersoluble groups $A$, $B$ and $C$. If the commutator subgroup $G'$ is nilpotent, then $G$ is supersoluble.

As a consequence of a Baer's result, in a finite group $G$ with nilpotent commutator subgroup, one can consider the largest normal and supersoluble subgroup $H$ of $G$; so, I think that I can prove the statement 1. by proving this other one:

- Let a finite group $G=AB$ be the product of two supersoluble subgroups and let the commutator subgroup $G'$ be nilpotent. If $H$ is the largest normal and supersoluble subgroup of $G$, then $A\leq H$ or $B\leq H$.

I thought that this could be the way, but I'm not sure. Can someone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: I have no idea how to solve the problem itself, but you second statement (the bulleted point) is not true in general. Let $G = A_4 \times A_4$. Then $H=G'$ is elementary abelian of order $16$. $G$ is the product $AB$ of two abelian subgroups of order 12 (take a 3 from one direct factor and a 4 from the other), neither of which is contained in $H$.